# Waiting for data to be retrieved from local storage

Tags: javascript, angular

When the gallery is loaded in my gallery app, a functioned is called to check whether the current user has liked an image in an array of images. If the user has liked the image, a solid heart icon is displayed on top of the image. If the hasn't liked the image, a heart outline icon is displayed.

Within the function, we get the current users index in an array of users. This information is retrieved from a user object which is stored in the browsers local storage. The problem I am having is that the function is called before the user data is retrieved from the local storage and I'm not sure how to get around this problem?

Here is the relevant html from the gallery-list component:

```
<div class="gallery-container">
    <div
      class="image-container"
      *ngFor="let image of galleryList">
      <div *ngIf="checkLike(image.imagePath)" class="heart-icon-container">
        <ion-icon name="heart" class="heart-icon" (click)="updateLike(image.imagePath)"></ion-icon>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="!checkLike(image.imagePath)" class="heart-icon-container">
        <ion-icon name="heart-outline" class="heart-icon" (click)="updateLike(image.imagePath)"></ion-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant code from the gallery-list ts file:

```
  currUsersIndex: number;

ngOnInit() {

    this.currUsersIndex = this.usersService.getCurrUserArrIndex();

}



 checkLike(imageUrl: string): boolean {
    const users = this.usersService.getUsers();

    if(this.isLoggedIn) {
      const FavouritesList = users[this.currUsersIndex].likes;

      if(FavouritesList.includes(imageUrl)) {
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
  }
    }
```

Finally, this is where the users index is retrieved from the users.service file:

```
private users: User[] = [];
 getCurrUserArrIndex() {

        const usersEmail = this.getCurrentUser().email;

        const users = this.getUsers();

        const usersIndex = users.findIndex(user => user.email === usersEmail);

        return usersIndex;

        }


 getCurrentUser() {

    const userData: {

         email: string,
         id: string,
         _token: string,
         _tokenExpirationDate: string

     } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUserData')); 

 return userData;

 }



    getUsers() {
        return this.users.slice();
    }
```

Please note, the users array is initially set to empty but it is set with the users from a firebase database when the app initializes.

The error message I am receiving in the console is: `"can't access property "likes", users[this.currUsersIndex] is undefined"`

Comment: users is not empty?

Comment: Sorry? The users array is set to empty initially see above: private users: User[] = [];

Comment: where is this.currUsersIndex defined ?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add this onto my OP. I have updated this now.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the issue here is that **`this.currUsersIndex`** is not set when you call `checkLike()` in the HTML.

Alternatively what i could recommend you is that, define a boolean variable in your component as,

```
checkLike = false;
```

and then call the function checkLike() after setting **`currUsersIndex`**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.currUsersIndex = this.usersService.getCurrUserArrIndex();
    this.checkLike();
}

checkLike(imageUrl: string): boolean {
    const users = this.usersService.getUsers();
    if(this.isLoggedIn) {
      const FavouritesList = users[this.currUsersIndex].likes;
      if(FavouritesList.includes(imageUrl)) {
          this.checkLike = true;
      } else {
          this.checkLike = false;
     }
  }
```

You must be already having the imageUrl in the component.ts just replace with that.

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately, I do not have the imageUrl in the component. What would be the best way of doing this? Sorry I am quite new to angular!

Comment: How would I get access to the URL?

Comment: you are looping over the images using ngFor which means that array is already available in the TS

Comment: Yes I have the array but I need the current element from the ngFor loop

Comment: ok then move this code inside checkLike   this.currUsersIndex = this.usersService.getCurrUserArrIndex();

Comment: and add a condition if(this.currUsersIndex)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added this.currUsersIndex = this.usersService.getCurrUserArrIndex(); to the checkLike method and I have added an if(this.currUsersIndex) but this still logs the error"TypeError: Cannot read property 'likes' of undefined at GalleryListComponent.checkLike" to the console

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to separate things IMO. You can update your code to this, this will be error-proof.

```
checkLike(imageUrl: string): boolean {
    const user = this.usersService.getCurrentUser();

    if(user && user.likes) {
      const FavouritesList = user.likes;
      return FavouritesList.includes(imageUrl);
    }

    return false
}

getCurrentUser() {
  const userData: {
        email: string,
        id: string,
        _token: string,
        _tokenExpirationDate: string
    } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUserData')); 

  const userEmail = userData.email;

  const users = this.getUsers();
  return users.find(user => user.email === usersEmail);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The getCurrentUser method is used in other components and changing it's returned value would affect other parts of my application so this isn't an option unfortunately